# Get last value of the column using java jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I'm very new to JPA. I'm trying to get the last value of a column from the database.

```
@Column(name="psd_id")
private long psdId;
```

I need to fetch this psdId from the DB which is the last value stored. I cannot use the auto generated as this is the scenario. I need to get the value and add 1 to the existing ID value. Any references would be greatly appreciated. I'm using mobile for this stack so I cannot copy the snippet too

Comment: What defines "last"? If it is chronological, you must have a timestamp in the row on which you can query.  A SQL database has no concept of "latest stored", or any other notion of row ordering. All order is imposed only at query time.

Comment: `select psdId from table order by psdId desc limit 1;`  or use `max`

Comment: I mean I want to fetch using JPA. not through simple queries

Comment: Last value is nothing but, the value of that column  in the last row.

Comment: and the "last row" is what? given that you have already been advised "A SQL database has no concept of latest stored, or any other notion of row ordering"

Comment: @Neil I mean the last row of a table. Psdid should be having some value in the last row which will be latest inserted row. I want that. Hope I have cleared your question.

Comment: Did you not read the first comment? There is no notion of row order. The only way you can define last is by defining the ORDER yourself in your QUERY. You haven't.

Comment: @Syed, Neil is right, 
 
As I am watching the command above mentioned, last inserted row means it is having the Max value only know. you are adding 1 to the previous value means you need to find the maximum value rather than last inserted rows. Cause database does not understand the word "Last inserted" row. :)

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge its better to use Hibernate which is the extended version of JPA. But the following case is worked fine for me. It may help you, Have a look on it.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb1 = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<YourClassName> cq1 = cb1.createQuery(YourClassName.class);
Root<YourClassName> root = cq1.from(YourClassName.class);
cq1.select(cb1.max(root.<Number>get("columnName")));
```

but the limitation is your column type should be of Number type(I mean - Int, BigInt, Decimal like this).

I hope it may help you to get the max number of id column. you can add 1 to max and proceed further.

Comment: Did you use hibernate or jpa. In my case I have to use only jpa as the application was designed.

Comment: I'm getting error on the last line at .select.. the method select in the type criteriaquery is not applicable for the arguments <expression number

Comment: I mentioned number for reference, you need to specify the Type of your column

Comment: By using JPA only you will get the answer., If possible post full trace

Comment: It is *always* better to use the STANDARD API rather than a vendors extensions.

Comment: Thats why I suggested HIbernate at first line of my answer :)

Comment: I'm very sorry as I'm posting this through mobile.. so cannot post the stack trace. My column type is long.  You can see it in my original post

Comment: No, you said It is better to use Hibernate (than JPA). This site is not for opinions, it is for solving problems.

Comment: When I use it , it throws me error of select method in the type criteriaquery is not applicable for the arguments(expression

Comment: then remove the <long> and try once again.. i will let you know ans soon

Comment: @NeilStockton as you said this site is not for opinion but at the results matters alot as far as consistancy and handy features are concerned

Comment: As I am watching the command above mentioned, last inserted row means it is having the Max value only know. you are adding 1 to the previous value means you need to find the maximum value rather than last inserted rows. Cause database does not understand the word "Last inserted" row. :)